# It takes too much time to operate on BLOB

Tags: java, jvm, blob

I have to read a `BLOB` column which contains only text. It worked quite efficiently (reading 100k `blob`s in 3 minutes) before but it is taking awful amount of time in a different environment although with same hardware.

Here's my code :-

```
    while (rs.next()) {
    is = rs.getBinaryStream(3);

    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    is.close();
    blobByte = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    String blob = new String(blobByte);
    String msisdn = rs.getString(2);

    blobData = blob.split("\\|");
            //some operations
            }
```

I took jstack at intervals of 5 seconds and found application always in this line :-

```
    blobData = blob.split("\\|");
```

And sometimes in :-

```
    new String(blobByte);
```

My java options :-

```
     -ms10g -mx12g -XX:NewSize=1g -XX:MaxNewSize=1g
```

Is some part of my code un-optimized? Or is there a significantly efficient way to read `BLOB`?

Comment: So you're saying that the exact same code performs differently in different environments? Did you check what the difference between those environments are? Also instead of just taking snapshots I'd suggest using jconsole's cpu sampling to get a low overhead "profile" of in which parts of the code the time is being spent (it's not as accurate as a proper profile but it should be sufficient to give you an idea of where to look for issues).

Comment: A description of the data in the blob might be helpful. Seems to be text fields separated by pipe characters. What's the average length of each blob? How many fields in each? And are you free to change the database schema?

Answer (score 1):

You get an `InputStream` for a BLOB to be able to avoid having the entire BLOB data in memory. But then, you do the entire opposite

- You use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to transfer the whole data into a `byte[]` array. Note that the data even exists twice in memory, once inside `ByteArrayOutputStream`’s own buffer, then in the copy created and returned by `baos.toByteArray()`
- Then, you convert the entire array into a potentially humongous `String` via `new String(blobByte)`, bearing the 3rd copying of the entire data (including the charset conversion).
- `split("\\|")` will run over the entire `String`, creating substrings for each sequence between the delimiters, which implies another copying of the entire data, into the substrings (minus the delimiter characters) by then, you have four copies of the entire data in memory, depending on the source’s buffering, it might be five times. Additionally, an array containing references to all these substrings is created and populated

Not all copy operation can be avoided. But we can avoid having the entire data in memory:

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\|")) {
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        String next = s.next();
        System.out.println(next);// replace with actual processing
    }
}
```

When you are able to process items individually, not keeping a reference to the previous item(s), these strings may get garbage collected, with a minor collection in the best case.

Even when a `String[]` array with all elements is required for your processing, which makes one copy of the entire data (in form of individual strings) unavoidable, you can avoid all the other copies:

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\|")) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(s.hasNext()) list.add(s.next());
    System.out.println(list);// replace with actual processing as List
    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]); // when an array really is required
}
```

Starting with Java 9, you can use

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\|")) {
    List<String> list = s.tokens().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list); // replace with actual processing as List
}
```

or

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\|")) {
    String[] array = s.tokens().toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // replace with actual processing
}
```

But processing the elements individually, without holding all of them in memory, is the preferred way.

---

Another possible optimization is to avoid multiple (internal) `Pattern.compile("\\|")` calls by doing it once yourself and passing the prepared `Pattern` instead of the `"\\|"` string to the `useDelimiter` method.

---

Note that all of these example use the system’s default charset encoding, just like your original code. Since the default charset of the environment running your code is not necessarily the same as for the database, you should be explicit, i.e. use `new Scanner(is, charset)`, just like you should have used `new String(blobByte, charset)` in your original code, instead of `new String(blobByte)`.

Or you use a CLOB in the first place.